# Как получить значение полей категории ACF?

Tags: wordpress

В рубрике создаю поле repeater + image и пытаюсь вывести это содержимое на странице категории и странице поста этой категории, но ни чего не получается.

```
<?php if( have_rows('slide') ):
while ( have_rows('slide') ) : the_row();
    $image = get_sub_field('img');
    $size = 'slider-inner';
    if( $image ) {
        echo wp_get_attachment_image( $image, $size );
    }
endwhile;
endif; ?>
```

и так, где 'category' - слаг рубрики

```
<?php if( have_rows('slide', 'category') ):
while ( have_rows('slide', 'category') ) : the_row();
    $image = get_sub_field('img');
    $size = 'slider-inner';
    if( $image ) {
        echo wp_get_attachment_image( $image, $size );
    }
endwhile;
endif; ?>
```

и так, где 9 - ID рубрики

```
<?php if( have_rows('slide', 9) ):
while ( have_rows('slide', 'category') ) : the_row();
    $image = get_sub_field('img');
    $size = 'slider-inner';
    if( $image ) {
        echo wp_get_attachment_image( $image, $size );
    }
endwhile;
endif; ?>
```

В чём ошибка? Как получить поля на странице category.php и на странице single.php?

И вот так тоже не работает

```
<?php
$queried_object = get_queried_object();
print_r( $queried_object );
if( have_rows('slide', 'poly_9') ): 
while ( have_rows('slide', 'poly_9') ) : the_row();
$image = get_sub_field('img');
$size = 'slider-inner';
if( $image ) { echo wp_get_attachment_image( $image, $size ); } 
endwhile;
endif; ?>
```

Выдаёт только это и всё, поля не получает:

```
WP_Term Object ( [term_id] => 9 [name] => Полиэтилен [slug] => poly [term_group] => 0 [term_taxonomy_id] => 9 [taxonomy] => category [description] => [parent] => 6 [count] => 0 [filter] => raw [cat_ID] => 9 [category_count] => 0 [category_description] => [cat_name] => Полиэтилен [category_nicename] => poly [category_parent] => 6 )
```

Comment: а какая общая задача? для чего именно нужно вывести эти поля? возможно, смогу помочь, если поясните подробнее.

Comment: Благодарю, нашёл решение, я не правильно указывал параметры.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно указывать в формате 'поле', 'таксономия_IDтаксономии'. Например,        `have_rows('slide', 'category_9').` 
Если вывод идет в файле архива или категории, можно так:

```
$queried_object = get_queried_object(); 
get_field('slide', $queried_object)
```